# Rails 404 on Ajax POST request despite route being defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I am running:

Rails 6
Ruby 2.5
Postgres 11.5
Mac OSX

I have the following routes defined:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'welcome#index'

  post 'search_controller/search'
end
```

I have the following code in my view:

```
 <%= form_for :search, :url => url_for(:controller => 'search_controller', :action => 'search'), remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search_term %>
  <%= f.submit %>
```

The resultant form code is:

```
<form action="/search_controller/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search[search_term]" id="search_search_term">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save Search" data-disable-with="Save Search">
</form>
```

Which to me looks as I would expect. I have also attempted a rails 6 style form as per :

```
<%= form_with(url: "/search_controller/search", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:term) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
```

which results in the same issue.

When I click the button, I get a HTTP 404 response:

```
rails-ujs.js:215 POST http://localhost:40250/search_controller/search 404 (Not Found)
```

When I run `rails routes` I get :

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        welcome#index
             search_controller_search POST   /search_controller/search(.:format)                                                      search_controller#search
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
    new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
   edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)
```

Note that you can see the route at search_controller_search.

Given these details, why am I getting the 404?

Comment: I would look at the source code of the page that gets rendered and verify the URL is what you expect. Also, look at the server log that gets generated when you submit the form - is it receiving what you think it should be?

Comment: First write your route code and the `form_for` syntax in accordance with rails 6 way... Refer `https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/index.html`

Comment: @dinjas I actually don't even appear to get an error from the server, no problem shows there at all, which is very odd. I run my server with : `foreman start -f Procfile.dev ` and The Procfile.dev has : web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server

Comment: @nileshkumar I have now tried that also - which doesn't help and has the the same issue - your suggestion does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the routes definition.

The solution was to change:

```
 post 'search_controller/search'
```

to:

```
post 'search_controller/search', to:"search#search"
```